# Using NancyFX with Razor view engine, how?

Tags: razor, nancy

I am using the latest NancyFX via nuget and have installed the Razor view engine also via nuget because the SSVE doesn't suit my needs (I need more conditional logic options).

The trouble is that all I can get is a 500 error anytime I call a Razor view:

```
Nancy.RequestExecutionException: Oh noes! ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Nancy.ViewEngines.DefaultViewCache.GetOrAdd[TCompiledView](ViewLocationResult viewLocationResult, Func`2 valueFactory)
   at Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorViewEngine.GetOrCompileView(ViewLocationResult viewLocationResult, IRenderContext renderContext, Assembly referencingAssembly, Type passedModelType)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute5[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
   at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , RazorViewEngine , ViewLocationResult , IRenderContext , Assembly , Object )
   at Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorViewEngine.GetViewInstance(ViewLocationResult viewLocationResult, IRenderContext renderContext, Assembly referencingAssembly, Object model)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute5[T0,T1,T2,T3,T4,TRet](CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1, T2 arg2, T3 arg3, T4 arg4)
   at Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorViewEngine.<>c__DisplayClass27.b__26(Stream stream)
   at Nancy.Responses.MaterialisingResponse.PreExecute(NancyContext context)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Nancy.NancyEngine.InvokeOnErrorHook(NancyContext context, ErrorPipeline pipeline, Exception ex)
```

I call the view here:

```
  return View["Content/views/IO/fileBrowser/ViewPage2.cshtml", dirListing];
```

There is no error till that point.

The view is totally blank, no code at all.  I have also tried view a new view specifying layout, still a 500 error.  I've tried referencing the model I am passing, also tried not passing the model.  Its all the same.  How are you meant to use Razor with Nancy?  What is the null reference?..

Nancy's super fun path has been nothing but frustration for me, nothing works out of the box :(

Answer (score 0):

In the root of your web application you should have a `views` folder, all paths are relative to the views folder.

Without knowing what your module looks like I will give you an example:

```cs
public class ProductsModule : NancyModule
{
  public ProductsModule()
  {
    Get["/"] = _ => 
    {
      ....

      return ["index", mymodel];
    }
  }
}
```

By default, not including other conventions including localization, Nancy will look for a folder called `products` inside `views` for a view named `index`.

So your folder structure should be:

```
-root
--views
---products
----index.cshtml
```

If the view is not found, it will then look back 1 directory inside `views`. so if your directory structure was:

```
-root
--views
---index.cshtml
```

Then it would find your view and render it.

There's much more to the discovery of views but this is the general design that you would use most often.

Comment: But it IS finding the view.  I tried renaming the view and that gives a view not found error as expected.  Plus I can change the extension to .html from cshtml and the view runs fine.  I just get some null reference when it tries to process the view as Razor.  I guess I need to find what that reference is but Ive not a clue.

Comment: Need more information about your view then. You could be missing the assemblies/namespaces that you've included in it in which case you need to add in a razor config file. https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Razor-View-Engine#configuring-razor-using-irazorconfiguration

Comment: Never did solve this. I ended up dumping nancy and going back to vanilla MVC. All of my dev work has been much easier since then, don't regret the decision to ditch the "super-duper-happy-path" in the slightest, for me it was the "roadblock-at-every-turn-path" ;(